# How to delete 2 files with the same name from different folders?

Tags: php, file-io

This is the php code:

```
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
  $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
  }
}
```

This is the form:

```
echo '<form method="post">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$file.'" name="delete_file" />';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete image" />';
echo '</form>';
```

I have 2 folders, the images and the thumbnails. I would like to delete the file with the same name from the two folders. With the above code I can delete the file just frome one folder. Should I duplicate the first code and put a second hidden input in the form or what's the simpliest way to solve this problem? (`$file` contains the path and the file of the thumbnail, and `$file2` contains the path and the file of the big image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The easy way:**

```
echo '<form method="post">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$file.'" name="delete_image" />';
  echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$file2.'" name="delete_thumb" />';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete image" />';
echo '</form>';
```

... then:

```
function deleteFile($filename) {
 if (file_exists($filename)) {
  unlink($filename);
  echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
 } else {
  echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
 }
}

if (array_key_exists('delete_image', $_POST)) {
 deleteFile($_POST['delete_image']);
}

if (array_key_exists('delete_thumb', $_POST)) {
 deleteFile($_POST['delete_thumb']);
}
```

---

**The better way** would be to have $file only contain the image file name (not it's path), and have all thumbs named the same way as their corresponding image. Then you could use:

```
echo '<form method="post">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$file.'" name="delete_image" />';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete image" />';
echo '</form>';
```

...then:

```
$folder_image = "images/";
$folder_thumb = "thumbs/";

function deleteFile($filename) {
 if (file_exists($filename)) {
  unlink($filename);
  echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
 } else {
  echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
 }
}

if (array_key_exists('delete_image', $_POST)) {
 $file_image = $_POST['delete_image'];
 deleteFile($folder_image.$file_image);
 deleteFile($folder_thumb.$file_image);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I prefer the last one :)

Answer (score 1):

Add folders array and foreach cycle

```
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
    $folders = ['images/', 'thumbnails/'];
    $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
    foreach($folders as $folder) {
        if (file_exists($folder . $filename)) {
            unlink($folder . $filename);
            echo 'File '. $folder . $filename.' has been deleted';
        } else {
            echo 'Could not delete '. $folder . $filename.', file does not exist';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could adapt your naming scheme so you need only 1 hidden input. your $file variables need only contain the filename and not the path. you keep the paths in your php script and append them to the value received from the form. you can use the `basename` function to strip the path in your form source. and you should use comma's in your echo statements.

```
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)){
 $filename='thumbs/'.$_POST['delete_file'];
 if (file_exists($filename)){
  unlink($filename);
  echo'File ',$filename,' has been deleted';
 } else {
  echo'Could not delete ',$filename,', file does not exist';
 }
 $filename='pics/'.$_POST['delete_file'];
 if (file_exists($filename)){
  unlink($filename);
  echo'File ',$filename,' has been deleted';
 } else {
  echo'Could not delete ',$filename,', file does not exist';
 }
}
```